# Terraform - how To make the 'local_file' resource to be recreated with every 'terraform apply'

Tags: terraform

I have a local_file resource in my terraform configuration,
the problem is how to tell terraform that i want this resource to be recreated every time my client will run 'terraform apply' even if nothing changed in the resource itself, how can i make this possible?
[local_file resource cant do what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is1Xd.png)

I am using triggers to do so in a null_resource but there is no such option in local_file resource.
[null_resource does what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W34cL.png)

Comment: Have you looked into `terraform -replace` or `terraform taint`?

Comment: From our [ask] help page: _DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)_

Comment: i dont want to use special terraform commands to do so, this code will be transferred to my client and i need hem to do only 'terraform apply', 
there is no way to make this resource recreate itself with every apply? this must be possible somehow

Answer (score 3):

Instead of local provider try template provider and create the file using null resource.So that trigger will take care of recreating the file.Tested like below

```
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/inventory.tpl")
   vars = {
      bastion_host = local.Mongo_Bastion_host
      key_file = var.private_key_file_path
    }
}

resource "null_resource" "copy-inventory" {
  triggers = {
    ip = local.random_id
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${data.template_file.inventory_cfg.rendered} >>inventory"
}
}
```

After terraform apply i reran terraform plan and able to see it is creating thefile again

Terraform will perform the following actions:

```
# null_resource.copy-inventory must be replaced
-/+ resource "null_resource" "copy-inventory" {
      ~ id       = "7011189362963809116" -> (known after apply)
      ~ triggers = {
          - "ip" = "f9f0f771-42ae-176e-3722-5b342665dea2"
        } -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```